# Compare list of files from a database using find to locate missing files

Tags: macos, bash, find, bsd

I have a list of 2000 files from a database that looks like this:

```
./aa/0f/unique-string/IMG_0987.JPG
./ab/cf/unique-string/IMG_0987.JPG
```

I want to compare that list to the actual directory contents in order to identify missing files.

The following command works individually, but not when I script it...

```
find . -false -samefile ./ab/cf/unique-string/IMG_0987.JPG
```

The closest I have come is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST=`cat ./list.lst`
find . -false -samefile "$TEST"
```

I am doing it wrong. what is the right way?

Comment: Pls take a look at my answer, for a faster solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your find command is using the entire contents of list.lst because you aren't feeding it through 1 line at a time.

```
while read f; do
find . -false -samefile "$f"
done<./list.lst
```

This reads the file list.lst 1 line at a time.

Comment: This is correct, but much slower than it need be. Pls see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By following your strategy, you will be making about *2000x2000 = 4,000,000* comparisons. You can do better than this.

Suppose the list is in *file_t1*; now we first generate a list of all files on the pc by means of

```
      find . -type f > file_t2
```

Then we sort both files:

```
      sort -n file_t1 > file1
      sort -n file_t2 > file2
```

Now we use *comm* to generate a list of differences:

```
      comm -X file1 file2
```

where:

```
      X = 12 -> lines that appear in **both** files
      X = 13 -> lines unique to file 2
      X = 23 -> lines unique to file1
```

This could be done with a one-liner, at the expense of clarity.

If you are interested: this is much faster because the files are already sorted (a strict requirement for *comm*), so they take of order N steps to compare, if the file size is N. Sorting requires *N log N* operations, which is thus the most expensive part of this solution, while the one you proposed requires *N^2* operations, which is significantly longer for your file sizes.